# how to trigger an event for an element when some other element is clicked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/2vvLe0ko/2/

I want to hide div with class droppointercontainer when the user clicks any other region except click me! div. and show the droppointercontainer div when the user clicks the click me! div.

how to do that with jQuery?

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="click" id="click1">click me!
                      <div class="droppointercontainer" id="droppointercontainer1">
                        <div class="droppointer"></div>
                        <div class="dropmenu" id="dropmenu1">
                            <h4>option1</h4>
                            <h4>option2</h4>
                            <h4>option3</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropmenutop"></div>
                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "click" id="click2">click me!
                      <div class="droppointercontainer" id="droppointercontainer2">
                        <div class="droppointer"></div>
                        <div class="dropmenu" id="dropmenu1">
                            <h4>option1</h4>
                            <h4>option2</h4>
                            <h4>option3</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropmenutop"></div>
                    </div>
  </div>
   <div class = "static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
   <div class = "static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
   <div class = "static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.click{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
.static{
  background-color:steelblue;
  height: 100px;
}
.droppointer{
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 0px; 
  z-index: 200;
}
.droppointercontainer{
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.dropmenutop{
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 199;
}
.dropmenu{
  /*display: none;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888888;
  background-color: #efefef;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 199;
}
h4{
  color:black;
}
```

javascript:

```
$("#click1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).children("#droppointercontainer1").fadeIn(200);
});
$("#click2").on("click", function(){
    $(this).children("#droppointercontainer2").fadeIn(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a function that does the job for all clicks...

**Edited and added a working proof link.**

```
$("#click1").on("click", function(){
    showMe(this);
});
$("#click2").on("click", function(){
     showMe(this);
});

$(document).on('click', function(__e){  
    if(!$(__e.target).hasClass('click')){
         $('.droppointercontainer').fadeOut(200);  
    }       
});

function showMe(__obj){
  $('.droppointercontainer').each(function(__idx, __el){
        if($(__el)[0] !== $(__obj).children('.droppointercontainer:first')[0]){
        if($(__el).css('opacity') >  0){
        $(__el).fadeOut(200);
      }
    }
});
$(__obj).children('.droppointercontainer:first').fadeIn(200);   
}
```

Proof

> https://jsfiddle.net/2vvLe0ko/7/

Comment: But droppointercontainer div should be hidden if we click any other element in the document except click me! div.

Comment: Fixed it, try again

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#click1") && !$(e.target).is("#click2")) {
        if ($('#click1').is(':visible') || $('#click2').is(':visible')) {
            $(".droppointercontainer").hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is "e" in the function parameter?

Comment: it is the `event` object, it automatically gets passed to the function from `.click()`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work correctly, if you click the first click me! div then second click me! does not work in a single click!

Comment: I updated the answer to include both divs. here is an updated fiddle with it working https://jsfiddle.net/2vvLe0ko/6/

Comment: And one last thing, only one dropdown should be visible at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle them. For that you can use a variable for each:

```
var drop1,drop2=false;
$("#click1").on("click", function(){
    drop1 ? $(this).children("#droppointercontainer1").fadeOut(200) : 
        $(this).children("#droppointercontainer1").fadeIn(200);
    $("#droppointercontainer2").fadeOut(200);
    drop1 = !drop1;
    drop2=false;
    });
    $("#click2").on("click", function(){
        drop2 ? $(this).children("#droppointercontainer2").fadeOut(200) : 
        $(this).children("#droppointercontainer2").fadeIn(200);
    $("#droppointercontainer1").fadeOut(200);
    drop1=false;
    drop2 = !drop2;
});
```

Comment: But droppointercontainer div should be hidden if we click any other element in the document except click me! div.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
 $(".droppointercontainer").hide();
  if($(event.target).is(".click")) {
    $(event.target).find(".droppointercontainer").show();
  }
})
```

```css
.click{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
.static{
  background-color:steelblue;
  height: 100px;
}
.droppointer{
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 0px; 
  z-index: 200;
}
.droppointercontainer{
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.dropmenutop{
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 199;
}
.dropmenu{
  /*display: none;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888888;
  background-color: #efefef;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 199;
}
h4{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click" id="click1">click me!
                      <div class="droppointercontainer" id="droppointercontainer1">
                        <div class="droppointer"></div>
                        <div class="dropmenu" id="dropmenu1">
                            <h4>option1</h4>
                            <h4>option2</h4>
                            <h4>option3</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropmenutop"></div>
                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "click" id="click2">click me!
                      <div class="droppointercontainer" id="droppointercontainer2">
                        <div class="droppointer"></div>
                        <div class="dropmenu" id="dropmenu1">
                            <h4>option1</h4>
                            <h4>option2</h4>
                            <h4>option3</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropmenutop"></div>
                    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
   <div class="static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
   <div class="static">Iam just  a tatic div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I'd go for a transparent overlay. When you click the overlay, the dropdown disappears. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d6yv60od/

```
$(".click").on("click", function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
  $(this).children(".droppointercontainer").fadeIn();
});
$('body').on('click', '.overlay', function() {
  $(this).remove();
  $(".droppointercontainer").fadeOut();
});
```

One advantage of this solution is that, in its simplicity, the dropdown remains open when you click on an iten. Unless you tell him to close of course, but this is another story :)